# Loop-based collision system only works with the last enemy added to vector

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml, push-back

I created an Enemy vector and used `push_back` twice to add two identical enemies. Inside a for loop, I created a collision system to prevent my player from going inside the enemies. However,for some reason it only works with the last enemy added.

I would like to know what should I do in order to make it work with every single enemy in that vector.

```
EnemyCounter = 0;
for (iter = EnemyArray.begin(); iter != EnemyArray.end(); iter++)
{

    EnemyArray[EnemyCounter].update(Seconds);

    window.draw(EnemyArray[EnemyCounter].CharacterSprite);

    if (player.RectShape.getGlobalBounds().intersects(EnemyArray[EnemyCounter].RectShape.getGlobalBounds()))
    {
        if (player.LastDirection == 0) player.canMoveDown = false;
        else if (player.LastDirection == 1) player.canMoveLeft = false;
        else if (player.LastDirection == 2) player.canMoveRight = false;
        else if (player.LastDirection == 3) player.canMoveUp = false;
    }
    if (!player.RectShape.getGlobalBounds().intersects(EnemyArray[EnemyCounter].RectShape.getGlobalBounds())) player.ResetCanMove();

    EnemyCounter++;

}
```

Comment: Looks to me like the problem is elsewhere. Maybe the same RectShape property is being copied to all Enemies?

Comment: All enemies inherit the RectShape from the Entity

Comment: Why aren't you using `iter` in the loop, but indexing instead?

Comment: Think for a few minutes about what happens to the player's state if you collide with the first enemy but not the second.

Comment: The player can't collide with the first enemy.

Comment: Set two breakpoints, one in the first "if" block and the other after the next if statement. Does your program stop on the first breakpoint?

Comment: Adding a break after the last else if  fixed the problem, thanks moonman239 :D.

Comment: I know this is fixed, but just something that might help your collision code run faster...  instead of checking for the intersection twice, you can use an else statement...

Comment: @MrFreeze How exactly was the problem solved? What was the solution?